# Get Minimum and maximum numbers from a list

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, data-structures

Assuming we have a list containing integers and we need to find min & max. What is the best way to do it ? I can think of following :

> 1. If number of reads are much higher than writes; keep the list in sorted manner. Whenever a number is added; add it in sorted manner.
>      Now to get min and max we can just get first and last element of this
>      list.
> 2. If number of writes are higher than reads; iterate on the list and return result. But this is O(n) which looks to be expensive.

Is there any other better way ?

Comment: Will you only add numbers ? (delete is not possible?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you can observe any mutation to the list, you could store (cache) the min and max values and possibly update the cached values when a number is added / removed. At this point, the order of the list doens't matter.

Comment: +1, if the max or min value are removed, finding min , max in the regular way may be expensive, this is the correct answer for cases where remove are rare

Comment: @Michael yes, you're right. Luckily, OP's problem statement doesn't even mention deletes O:)

Comment: I wrote him a comment, and you received an up-vote since he didn't mentioned if ;-)

Comment: +1, with this solution and no delete, you don't even need to keep the list.

Comment: I have proposed interesting solution for the delete cases, if it is wrong please correct me

Answer (score 2):

You could use the Collection.max() and Collection.min() static methods for that...

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html

Use SortedSet to have the collection automatically sorted.

Answer (score 2):

I will suggest an interesting idea:

Assuming you do have frequent deletes although more reads than writes, you may hold an array of items (object which represents the integer with two references to the min and max of already added items) with cached reference to the **previous** min and max value (the difference from @akaIDIOT solution is that this are only references).

Each value in the stack point to the previous max value and previous min value.

Add item will also take O(1), and finding out the minimum and maximum will also take O(1).

Delete Item is described in the update:

The disadvantage is more memory consumption.

@akaIDIOT has mentioned in his comments a case which i have missed. what if you have multiple max or min values.

In this case and other cases also, deleting max value will demand updating of all objects that point to it , which will be max O(n), but i think that in average it will still stay O(1).
If all values are **distinct** this will be always O(1)

Comment: Interesting idea. Haven't tested this, but what will this do if there's more than one stored instance of the current maximum value and it is deleted? (won't the pointers get updated to an incorrect new maximum?)

Comment: Interesting, so it looks as if there are multiple similar values, deleting max value will demand updating of all objects that point to it , which will be max O(n), but in average it will still stay O(1), i will update my answer

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a `min/max heap` like data structure (red black tree) to keep the integers. Get min/max will take `O(1)` time and inserting a new element will take `O(log n)` time.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Min-max_heap

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you support delete of integers from your list, regardless which is higher (read or writes), having a sorted list makes things easier and gives better performance.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a custom list that maintains the Min and Max values. This will give you O(1) insertion, O(1) reading of Min and Max, and O(N) deletion, but only in the case where you are deleting min or max.

Pseudo-code:

```
public MinMaxList
{
    property Min; 
    property Max;

    method Add (int newValue)
    {
        if (Min is null OR newValue < Min)
            Min = newValue;

        if (Max is null OR newValue > Max)
            Max = newValue;
    }

    method Delete (int value)
    {
        if (value = Min or value = Max)
            //Rescan list to determine new Min and Max values. This is O(N).
    }

}
```

Comment: @Michael Yeah, I can see that now. I was writing my answer while he posted it.